# Name of array in result of json_decode()

Tags: php, json

If I do a json_decode like this:

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata);
echo var_dump($json);
```

I get something like this:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) 
{ ["QRY_JISGesch"]=> array(3) 
    { [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (8) 
        { ["JISGeschID"]=> int(7) ["StandorteID"]=> int(0) ["FSKID"]=> int(23) 
        } 
    [1]=> object(stdClass)#3 (8) 
        { ["JISGeschID"]=> int(8) ["StandorteID"]=> int(0) ["FSKID"]=> int(22) 
        } 
    [2]=> object(stdClass)#4 (8) 
        { ["JISGeschID"]=> int(9) ["StandorteID"]=> int(0) ["FSKID"]=> int(1)
        } 
    } 
}
```

How do I find out "QRY_JISGesch" in code?

Comment: use "find" from your editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`reset()`](https://php.net/reset) to get the first member of an object (or an array).

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata);
$first = reset($json);
```

If you only want the get the first "key", you can use [`key()`](https://php.net/key);

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata);
$key = key($json); // QRY_JISGesch
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the answer I was looking for. key($json) did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will help you :-

```
$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);
// true means objects will be converted into associative arrays
```

and you can access `QRY_JISGesch` like this way :- `$json['QRY_JISGesch']`

Comment: Don't think that this solves the problem - if `QRY_JISGesch` is unknown, it is unknown

Comment: I'm aware of that second param in json_decode, but this doesn't help me here. And I also know that I can access the var with $json['QRY_JISGesch']. But I need to do a function that can handle different values, other than QRY_JISGesch.

Comment: @klammerauf You want to check that `QRY_JISGesch` exists or not. correct??

Answer (score 0):

Is there only one item given in the array, and you are not interested in the name itself, but the values? Then [array_values](http://php.net/array_values) could help.

Otherwise, you could use [array_keys](http://php.net/array_keys) to read all keys and iterate over them? Or use a `foreach` loop which does not care about the array key neither.

Comment: array_values($json) gives a warning "array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given". array_values($json[0]) gives a fatal error "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: array_keys($json) gives the same warning as array_values.

Comment: Ah, yeah - this could have worked with `$json = json_decode($jsondata, true);`

Answer (score 0):

`get_object_vars (object $object)` will give you a list of all accessible properties of the returned object.

Comment: get_object_vars($json) result is "Array"